# How to email content from local storage using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on a chrome extension that will take input into the text area html form, and display it using a save button below into the myLeads array.

I am stuck on trying to build in an email button/function to take the value from the myLeads array and send that content in an email. My code I have thus far is below, it pulls up the user's desired email and pre-populates the example-email as the recipient.

I would like this to instead populate the value from the myLeads array, as well as the user's email address (or none at all and allow them to input this). I would appreciate any assistance thank you all in advance.

```js
let myLeads = []
const inputEl = document.getElementById("input-el")
const inputBtn = document.getElementById("input-btn")
const ulEl = document.getElementById("ul-el")
const deleteBtn = document.getElementById("delete-btn")
const leadsFromLocalStorage = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("myLeads"))
const tabBtn = document.getElementById("tab-btn")

console.log(leadsFromLocalStorage)


if (leadsFromLocalStorage) {
    myLeads = leadsFromLocalStorage
    render(myLeads)
} else {
    console.log("No local storage data")
}



inputBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {

    myLeads.push(inputEl.value)
    inputEl.value = ""
    localStorage.setItem("myLeads", JSON.stringify(myLeads) )
    render(myLeads)

})

deleteBtn.addEventListener("dblclick", function(){
    myLeads = [];
    localStorage.clear();
    render(myLeads);
    
})




function render(leads) {
    let listItems = ""
    for (let i = 0; i < leads.length; i++) {
        listItems += `
            <li>
                    ${leads[i]}
            </li>
        `
    }
    ulEl.innerHTML = listItems  
}




const emailBtn = document.getElementById("email-btn")

emailBtn.addEventListener("dblclick", function() {
    const sendMail = () => {
        const link =
          "mailto:example-email.com" +
          "&subject=" +
          encodeURIComponent("This is my subject") +
          "&body=" +
          encodeURIComponent(myLeads.value);
        window.location.href = link;
      };
      sendMail();
})
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <textarea cols="40" rows="5" id="input-el"> </textarea>

        <button id="input-btn">SAVE INPUT</button>
        <button id="delete-btn">DELETE ALL</button>
        <button id="email-btn">EMAIL LEADS</button>
        <ol id="ul-el">
        </ol>
        <script src="index.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can recommend a few changes to apply:

1. Use `?` symbol before your first `link` parameter instead of `&`. When you create a URL with parameters the first parameter should be added after `?`, others after `&`
2. Send just `myLeads` instead of `myLeads.value`, you don't have a `value` property inside an array. Or if you want to show each element of `myLeads` on a separate line, you can do `myLeads.join('\n')`.

Example:

```
const link =
    "mailto:example-email.com" +
    "?subject=" +
    encodeURIComponent("This is my subject") +
    "&body=" +
    encodeURIComponent(myLeads.join('\n'));
```